# How to calculate some values using shell script between all files so that the output is all-by-all matrix?

Tags: java, linux, shell, bioinformatics

I am having some problems getting a shell script running properly. I am not getting the desired output. I have 3 files:

Sample File1

```
>A3IC_00
ATGGACCGCCTCGTCAACCGGATTCGCGCCAACGCGTGGGGTTCGCTCACGGCCATCCCCGAACTGCTCGGCGTCGCCCCCACCGGCGAACCGCAGGCCGAGCTGTGGATGGGAGCCCACCCGGGCGCGCCCTCCCGGATCGACCGGGGCCGCGGGCCGTGCTCGCTGGTCGAGCTGATCGCCGCCGACCCCGAGGGCGAGCTCGGCGCGGACACCGCGGCCCGGTTCGGCCCGCGGCTGCCGTTCCTGCTCAAGGTGCTGGCCGCGGAGGAGCCGCTGTCGCTCCAGGTGCACCCGGACGCGATCCAGGCCCGGCACGGCTACGCGGAGGAGGAGGCGCGCGGCGTCCCGATCGACGCGCCGCACCGCAACTACCGCGACTCCAGCCACAAGCCGGAGATGATCTGCGCGCTCGGCGACTTCGAGGGCCTGGTCGGCTATCGCGAGATCGCCGAGACACTCAAGCTGCTCGACGCCCTCGACGTCCCGGAACTGGCTCCGTTCGCACGCGCGTTGCGCAATCCCGACCAGGAGGCGGCACTGCGCGCGGCGACCACGCACGTGCTCATGCTGCCCGCCCGCCTGCGCACCGGCGTGGTCGACGCGGTGGCCGCGGCCTGTCGGCGGCTGGCCGCGAACG
```

Sample File2

```
>AW19M42_00
ATGGACCGGCTCTCCAACACCGTGCGCCCGTACGCCTGGGGCTCCACCACAGCCATCCCCGCCCTGCTGGGTGTCGCCCCCACCGGCGAGCCCCAGGCCGAGATGTGGATGGGCGCCCACCCCGGGGCCCCCTCCCGGATAACCCGCACCGGCCCCGCCACCGCACCCGACGCCACGCCCGGCACCCCGCAGACCCCCACCGAGCAGCCCCTCACCGACGTCATCGCCGCCGATCCGGTGGGCGAGCTGGGCCCGGCCGCCGTCGAGAAGTTCGGCCCCCGGCTCCCCTTCCTCCTCAAGCTGCTCGCCGCCGGAGCACCGCTCTCCCTCCAGGTCCACCCCGACCTCGCCCAGGCACAGCAGGGTTACGCGGACGAGGAGCGCCGGTCCGTCCCGATCGACGCCCCCCACCGCACGTACAAGGACGCCAACCACAAGCCCGAACTGATCTGCGCGCTCACCCCCTTCGACGGCCTGTGCGGCTTCCGCCGGCCCATCGAGGCGGCCGAGACGATGGAGGCGCTGGGCGTCGACTCCCTCAAGCCCTACGCCGACCTGCTGCGCGCCCACCCCGAGGAGGACGCCCTGCGCGAGGTCCTCACGGCGATCCTCACCGCGGACCCGGCGCAGATGGCGGAGACGGTGACCGCCGCGGCCGCGGCCGCGGAACGGCTCGGCGGCGCCTACGCCCCGTACGCGCGCATCGCCCACCACTTCCCGGGCGACGCGGGCGTCATCGCGGCCATGCTGCTGAACTACGTGCGACTCCAGCCCGGCGAGGCGCTGTTTCTCGGCGCCGGGGTCCCGCACGCCTACCTCGACGGCCTCGGCGTCGAGATCA
```

Sample File3

```
>B072_00
ATGGACCGCCTCACCAACACCGTCCGCCCCTACGCCTGGGGCTCCACCACCGCCATCCCGCGGCTCGTCGGCGCCGAGCCGACCGGCGAACCCCAGGCCGAGATGTGGATGGGCGCCCACCCCGGCGCCCCCTCCCGCACCGAGCGCGGCCCGCTGAACGAGGTCATCGACGCGGCCCCCGCGCAGGAGCTGGGCGAGCCGGCCGTGACCAAGTTCGGCCCCCGCCTCCCCTTCCTCCTCAAGCTGCTCGCCGCGGGCGCCCCCCTCTCCCTCCAGGTGCATCCGAACCTCCAGCAGGCGAAGGAGGGTTACGAGAAGGAAGAGGCCCAGGGCGTTCCCATCGACGCCCCGCACCGCAACTACAAGGACGCCAACCACAAGCCCGAACTCATCTGCGCGCTCACCGAGTTCGACGGCCTGTGCGGCTTCCGCGCCCCCGAGGAGGCGGCCCGGCTCCTCGAAGGCCTCGGCGTCGACAGCCTCAAGCCGTACGTGGACCTGCTGCGCGCCCACCCCGAGGAGGCCGCGCTGCGCGAGGTCCTCACGGCCGTCCTGTCCGCGGACCTCGCCGAGATGACGGCCACCGTCACCGAGGCGACCGCCGCCGCCCAGCGCATCGGCGGCGACTACGAGCCGTACGCGGGCATCGCCCACCACTACCCCGGCGACCCGGGCGTCATCGCGGCCATGCTCCTCAATCACGTACGCCTGCAGCCGGGCGAGGCGCTCTTCCTCGGCGCCGGCGTCCCGCACGCGTACCTGAACGGCCTCGGCGTCGAGATCATGGCCAACTCCGACAACGTCCTGCGCTGCGGCCTCACGCCGAAGCACGTCG
```

...and I need to do some calculations for all the possible pairs between these 3 files, i.e. the output should be 3x3 matrix. The script reads name of the 3 files from *list2.txt*.

Here is my code:

```
list=`cat list2.txt`
for id in $list
do
echo "processing .........................................$id"

orthoani=`java -jar OAT_cmd.jar -blastplus_dir ~/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin/ \
          -method ani -fasta1 $id.fasta -fasta2 $id.fasta | \
          grep "OrthoANI :"`
echo "$id $id $orthoani" >> tmp00-orthoANI.txt
done
```

Sample Output:

```
    A3IC_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
    AW19M42_00 AW19M42_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
    B072_00 B072_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
```

Desired output:

```
    A3IC_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
    A3IC_00 AW19M42_00 OrthoANI : 70.0 (%)
    A3IC_00 B072_00 OrthoANI : 65.0 (%)
    AW19M42_00 AW19M42_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
    AW19M42_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 70.0 (%)
    AW19M42_00 B072_00 OrthoANI : 87.0 (%)
    B072_00 B072_00 OrthoANI : 100.0 (%)
    B072_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 65.0 (%)
    B072_00 AW19M42_00 OrthoANI : 87.0 (%)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide samples of what's in each of the three files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The contents of each file is as follows:

    >A3IC_00
ATGGACCGCCTCGTCAACCGGATTCGCGCCAACGCGTGGGGTTCGCTCACGGCCATCCCCGAACTGCTCGGCGTCGCCCCCACCGGCGAACCGCAGGCCGAGCTGTGGATGGGAGCCCACCCGGGCGCGCCCTCCCGGATCGACCGGGGCCGCGGGCCGTGCTCGCTGGTCGAGCTGATC

    The first line of each file is a header (starting with > followed by ID).        The remaining lines represent the DNA sequence. Others files have similar content. The program "OAT_cmd.jar" in my script calculates percent identity between any two given files. So I want to automate the process for all possible combinations. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that's unclear... there's only one header `>A3IC_00` shown, followed by about 217 characters, so it looks like there's only one file.    Please include the samples by re-editing your question -- it's better *not* to put samples in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with 3 sample files.

Comment: In the desired output, please explain what the second field is.  For example, in `AW19M42_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 70.0 (%)`, where does `A3IC_00` come from?

Comment: AW19M42_00, A3IC_00 & B072_00 are the file names as well as headers (first line starting with ">") of individual files. Names of all these 3 files are provided to the script through list2.txt. So AW19M42_00 A3IC_00 OrthoANI : 70.0 (%) means 70%  similarity between these two files. Similarly I need similarity scores between all possible pairs of these 3 files.

Comment: Please clarify both whether the order of the filenames matters, (i.e. is `A3IC_00  B072_00` to be regarded as a duplicate of `B072_00 A3IC_00`), and whether repetition is allowed, (i.e. `A3IC_00 A3IC_00`).

Comment: Thanks. Order of file names does not matter. It's also OK to have repetitions as it will act as control. Pairing of all possible combinations is important.

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. The desired output includes lines where the first two fields are different, like:

   ```
   B072_00 AW19M42_00 OrthoANI : 87.0 (%)
   ```

   At present that output is **impossible** because the code that outputs the first two fields uses the *same variable twice* (i.e. `"$id $id..."`):

   ```
   echo "$id $id $orthoani" >> tmp00-orthoANI.txt
   ```
2. Since this code always seems to compare `$id.fasta` to *itself*:

   ```
   java -jar OAT_cmd.jar -blastplus_dir ~/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin/ \
        -method ani -fasta1 $id.fasta -fasta2 $id.fasta
   ```

   The result must be *%100*.
3. Needlessly complicated:

   ```
   list=`cat list2.txt`
   for id in $list
       < .....etc. >
   done
   ```

   Simpler:

   ```
   while read id
       < .....etc. >
   done < list2.txt
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I still get the same output as shown in sample output. Even after replacing "for loop" with "while loop"

Comment: Replacing the `for` with the `while` is better code, but it shouldn't change the output.  Re "*same output*", see Observation #1 -- given that code, it's **impossible** to get the desired output -- therefore the code must be changed to conform to the spec, but currently your spec is too incomplete to answer.